# Dialog UI - hide effect doesnt trigger complete event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, hide

I don't know if it's a bug old I am doing something wrong but I am working with jQuery Dialog UI using hide/show effects (fade), and complete event doesnt trigger in case of hide effect.

```
$("#tester").dialog({
    closeonescape: true,
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function(){ alert('complete show') }
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function(){ alert('complete hide') }
    }    
});
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XXLeC/).

Comment: is `complete` a correct keyword name for `hide` ?

Comment: I thought it's should be the same as the keyword for show.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The correct answer is close property on $.fn.dialog properties.

It is triggered after animation is complete. Nevertheless I think it's misleading, because "open" event is trigger before animation complete while "close" waits till the end.